# Fitting Logistic AR1 via R-based glmmTMB in Python via rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2, glmmtmb

I'm trying to fit a logistic regression with serial autocorrelation, or AR1 errors, in Python.  Unfortunately, `statsmodels` has not gotten this far yet;  however, R-package `glmmTMB` has.  I'm thisclose (seemingly) to pulling this off via `rpy2` in Python, but I'm stuck.

My R skills (and the error:  `RRuntimeError: Error in na.fail.default(as.ts(x)) : missing values in object`) suggest a need to modify the `na.action` argument to function `glmmTMB` (in the package `glmmTMB`), but this is not necessary within R -- my example fits there and is happy.  So, I suspect something else in the Python-to-R chain is awry.

My money is on the factor characterization necessary for variables `time` and `group` to the `ar` piece in the `formula`.  Does anyone see what I can do?  Am I not creating the factor variables correctly?

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri 
from rpy2 import robjects as ro
import pandas as pd

# Make some data.  
data = {'Success': [10, 20, 30, 11, 14, 16, 18, 29, 17, 19], 
        'Failure': [12, 25, 61, 8, 22, 21, 10, 16, 15, 19]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Allow rpy2 to talk to pandas.  
pandas2ri.activate() 

# Bring in some R stuff.  
base = importr('base')
utils = importr('utils')
stats = importr('stats')
glmmTMB = importr('glmmTMB')

# Modify the dataframe for use with glmmTMB.  
df['time'] = range(1, len(df) + 1)
df['group'] = 1

# Convert df to an R dataframe.  
r_df = pandas2ri.py2ri(df)

# Add in group as a factor to R dataframe r_df.
col_group = ro.vectors.FactorVector(r_df.rx2('group'))
assessor_col_index = df.columns.get_loc('group')   # python 
r_df[assessor_col_index] = col_group

# Add in time as a factor to R dataframe r_df.  
col_time = ro.vectors.FactorVector(r_df.rx2('time'))
assessor_col_index = df.columns.get_loc('time')   # python 
r_df[assessor_col_index] = col_time

# Take a look at stuff.  Looks correct.  
print(r_df)
print(col_group)
print(col_time) 

# This works.  Normal outcome.  
m0 = ro.r.glmmTMB(formula=ro.r('Success ~ 1'), data=r_df)
# print(m0[1][0])

# This works.  Logistic outcome.  
m1 = ro.r.glmmTMB(formula=ro.r('cbind(Success, Failure) ~ 1'), family=ro.r('binomial'), data=r_df)
# print(m1[1][0])

# This does not work.  AR1 with factors, per documentation.  
# m2 = ro.r.glmmTMB(formula=ro.r("cbind(Success, Failure) ~ 1 + ar(time + 0 | group)"), family=ro.r('binomial'), data=r_df)
# m2[1][0]


# Added for clarity, 2021-03-08:  Other variations using na_action argument.  

# m3  = ro.r.glmmTMB(formula=ro.r("cbind(Success, Failure) ~ 1 + ar(time + 0 | group)"), family=ro.r('binomial'), data=r_df, na_action=na_omit)            
# name 'na_omit' is not defined.

# m4  = ro.r.glmmTMB(formula=ro.r("cbind(Success, Failure) ~ 1 + ar(time + 0 | group)"), family=ro.r('binomial'), data=r_df, na_action=ro.r(na_omit))     
# name 'na_omit' is not defined. 

# m5  = ro.r.glmmTMB(formula=ro.r("cbind(Success, Failure) ~ 1 + ar(time + 0 | group)"), family=ro.r('binomial'), data=r_df, na_action='na_omit')        
# Error in na.fail.default(as.ts(x)): missing values in object 

# m6  = ro.r.glmmTMB(formula=ro.r("cbind(Success, Failure) ~ 1 + ar(time + 0 | group)"), family=ro.r('binomial'), data=r_df, na_action=ro.r('na_omit'))  
# Error in (function(expr, envir=parent.frame(), enclos=if(is.list(envir) || object 'na_omit' not found)))
 
# m7  = ro.r.glmmTMB(formula=ro.r("cbind(Success, Failure) ~ 1 + ar(time + 0 | group)"), family=ro.r('binomial'), data=r_df, na_action=na.omit)          
# name 'na' is not defined 

# m8  = ro.r.glmmTMB(formula=ro.r("cbind(Success, Failure) ~ 1 + ar(time + 0 | group)"), family=ro.r('binomial'), data=r_df, na_action=ro.r(na.omit))      
# name 'na' is not defined

# m9  = ro.r.glmmTMB(formula=ro.r("cbind(Success, Failure) ~ 1 + ar(time + 0 | group)"), family=ro.r('binomial'), data=r_df, na_action='na.omit')        
# Error in na.fail.default(as.ts(x)): missing values in object

# m10 = ro.r.glmmTMB(formula=ro.r("cbind(Success, Failure) ~ 1 + ar(time + 0 | group)"), family=ro.r('binomial'), data=r_df, na_action=ro.r('na.omit'))   
# Error in na.fail.default(as.ts(x)): missing values in object
```

Answer (score 1):

If the named parameter `na.action` is in the signature of the function `glmmTMB()` you should be able to do

```
m = ro.r.glmmTMB(<blah>, na_action=<your value>)
```

The doc is here: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.4.x/html/robjects_functions.html?highlight=function#callable

Comment: I included my initial attempts involving the inclusion of this variable, and their inability to complete without an error.  Did you try your suggestion on my toy example?  Do you see anything I missed?